# UITableView not populating cell completely until moved off screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform, xcode6

I am using Parse to populate cells in a tableview. Each cell contains a username, the user's picture, and the actual post content. When I run the app, the username and post content is loaded into each cell. However the picture is not loaded until the cell is moved off screen and then moved back. Here is my code involving the query:

```
-(void)retrieveFromParse {

PFQuery *retrievePosts = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Posts"];
[retrievePosts orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
retrievePosts.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
[retrievePosts findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

    if (!error) {

        postsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];

         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        });
    }
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
    });
}];
}
```

Here is the code for the tableview:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

postCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PostCellOne"];


if (postCell == nil ) {

    postCell = [[PostTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"PostCellOne"];


}

postCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
postCell.posterName.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
postCell.postContent.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

PFObject *postObject = [postsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
postCell.posterName.text = [postObject objectForKey:@"posterName"];
postCell.postContent.text = [postObject objectForKey:@"postContent"];
UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithFrame:postCell.posterImage.frame];
[postCell.posterImage addSubview:spinner];
spinner.color = [UIColor whiteColor];
[spinner startAnimating];
imageFile = [postObject objectForKey:@"posterPicture"];
[imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [spinner removeFromSuperview];
        postCell.posterImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        [tableView reloadInputViews];

        });
    }

    else {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [spinner removeFromSuperview];
        });
    }
}];

return postCell;

}
```

Comment: What if you wait a little while and not move the tableview does the picture show up?  It probably takes a while to download.

Comment: Threading issue as pointed below

Comment: Just curious what does this line do? [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];

Comment: I have a refresh control so you can pull to refresh the table view. The control has an action that runs the retrieveFromParse method. So that lines stops the refresh control once everything needed is retrieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Parse to populate cells in a tableview. Each cell contains a username, the user's picture, and the actual post content. When I run the app, the username and post content is loaded into each cell. However the picture is not loaded until the cell is moved off screen and then moved back. Here is my code involving the query:

```
-(void)retrieveFromParse {

PFQuery *retrievePosts = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Posts"];
[retrievePosts orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
retrievePosts.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
[retrievePosts findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

    if (!error) {

        postsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];

         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        });
    }
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
    });
}];
}
```

Here is the code for the tableview:

```
 -(void)imageFromImageFile:(PFFile *)imageFile forCell:(PostTableViewCell *)cell
{
    PostTableViewCell *workingCell = cell;
    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithFrame:postCell.posterImage.frame];
    [workingCell.posterImage addSubview:spinner];
    spinner.color = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [spinner startAnimating];
    [imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            if(workingCell == cell){
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [spinner removeFromSuperview];
                    workingCell.posterImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                    [workingCell setNeedsLayout];

                });
            }else{

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [spinner removeFromSuperview];
                });
            }
        }
    }];

}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    postCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PostCellOne"];


    if (postCell == nil ) {

        postCell = [[PostTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"PostCellOne"];


    }

    postCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    postCell.posterName.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    postCell.postContent.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    PFObject *postObject = [postsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    postCell.posterName.text = [postObject objectForKey:@"posterName"];
    postCell.postContent.text = [postObject objectForKey:@"postContent"];

    imageFile = [postObject objectForKey:@"posterPicture"];
    cell.posterImage.image = nil;
    [self imageFromImageFile:imageFile forCell:cell];

    return postCell;

}
```